# UL LI tags in html create blank space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

So I have this ul's li's and nav is changed in css to inline but for some reason when i put those few lines on the top of the page they create blank area like 3-4 lines down which I can't get rid of

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><span style="position: relative; top: -19px;"><a href="champions.php">Champions</a></span></li>
<li><span style="position: relative; top: -19px;"><a href="items.php">Items</a></span></li>
<li><span style="position: relative; top: -19px;"><a href="changes.php">Changes</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why are you using position relative? At the very least try deleting the `top:-19px`- http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IuLfJ

Comment: Have you got some separate CSS as well, or are you just referring to your inline styling (just this doesn't set the elements to display:inline as you seem to suggest).

Comment: What look are u trying to achieve?

Comment: @Paulie_D great one cant be more specific

Comment: @Higeath:In accordance with what is written by TrueBlueAussie i suggest also reading these pages:http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/ and http://www.cssreset.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rule of UL/LIs. Get rid of the default formatting:

```
#nav.ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle to mess around with: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4ctUx/

Answer (score 2):

Inline content is whitespace-sensitive, so you will have spaces between the element.  This is typically why people will use `float` rather than `inline` when they want elements to line up next to each other.

Here is a simplified example demonstrating what I *think* your problem is:

http://jsfiddle.net/rH24P/

I would change this to use `float: left` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/rH24P/1/

Updated CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this http://jsfiddle.net/4QR2v/

Remove your inline styling and use the following CSS instead:

```
#nav{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav li{
    display:inline;
}
```

The `margin:0` and `padding:0` removes the default formatting on lists (which may be the gap you're referring to). And the `display:inline` puts everything on one line.